# SolrDocumentList to JSON is ignoring numFound property in solrj response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, solr, solrj

below is my solrDocumentList data

```
{numFound=16,start=0,docs=[SolrDocument{cluster=Horton, source=MUSE}]}
```

But While returning as Json the numFound and start property is getting ignored in response.

code

```
    // Preparing Solr query
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery(searchString);

    // Adding the field to be retrieved

    query.addField("*");
    query.setStart(start);
    query.setRows(rows);


    // Executing the query
    QueryResponse queryResponse = Solr.query(query);
    // Storing the results of the query
    SolrDocumentList docs = queryResponse.getResults();

    System.out.println("queryResponse is :" + docs);

    Solr.close();


    return docs;
```

OutPut Response :

```
[{cluster=Horton, source=MUSE}]
```

I am expecting output like below,(array of json)

```
[doc: {cluster=Horton, source=MUSE},
 numFound:0
]
```

Anyhelp Appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how spring-boot converts returned values to JSON, but my guess is that when you return the resulting list directly, it'll be used as a list (since it implements the List and Collection interfaces, but typed as containing SolrDocuments). This list represents the documents, and not the request itself. You can manually return a map instead, and attach the values you need under the expected keys.

Answer (score -1):

You will get numFound using the following method.

queryResponse.getResults().getNumFound();

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_5_1/solr-solrj/index.html?org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/QueryResponse.html

Comment: Yes. If I am printing my output (docs) in console its printing with numFound. But if I return it to the response then its not available in output json response. Your help is appreciated.